# Axis labels are clipped (in BarChart)

Tags: plotting

I have created a bar chart with the below code. My $x$ axis labels have been cut in half for some reason. My $x$ axis heading is also missing. I tried using `Placed -> Below` instead of `Placed -> Axis` as proposed in an answer to a similar question about labels bieng cut in half but this does not seem to work at all with my version (*Mathematica* 9). When I resize the chart the axis labels eventually stop bieng cut in half when the chart is huge but my main $x$ axis heading is still missing. I can't use Labeled `[{xheading,yheading}, {position,position}]` becasue it is not a graphics object and I need my bar chart to be a graphics object so I can use it in `Show` later.

```
data = {{71.74887892, 75.81967213}, {75.81120944, 77.88018433},
        {0.6600660066, 1.673640167}, {84.74576271, 79.34782609},
        {76.4, 79.49790795}, {78.84267631, 80.11782032},
        {71.51515152, 74.30249633}, {85.57692308, 79.37062937},
        {71.875, 74.3772242}, {66.28477905, 64.25233645},
        {1.490066225, 1.914414414}, {1.474926254, 1.763224181}};
dataLabel = {"DT401       ", "DT402       ", "DT403       ", "DT404       ", 
             "DT405       ", "DT406       ", "DT407       ", "DT408       ", 
             "DT409       ", "DT410       ", "DT411       ", "DT412       "};
label = "Truck";

BarChart[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 100}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[l, Axis], Placed[{"", ""}, Bottom]}, 
 PlotLabel -> label, 
 AxesLabel -> {label, label}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ImagePadding -> {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`:

```
BarChart[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 100}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[l, Axis], Placed[{"", ""}, Bottom]}, 
 PlotLabel -> label, AxesLabel -> {label, label}, ImagePadding -> {{10, 40}, {20, 20}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the right answer and the efficient edit of the question

Comment: Thanks @cormullion. I just get this itch to edit when I see a post that is not stripped to the obvious sufficient minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Try tweaking the `PlotRange`:

```
 BarChart[{{71.74887892, 75.81967213}, {75.81120944, 
   77.88018433}, {0.6600660066, 1.673640167}, {84.74576271, 
   79.34782609}, {76.4, 79.49790795}, {78.84267631, 
   80.11782032}, {71.51515152, 74.30249633}, {85.57692308, 
   79.37062937}, {71.875, 74.3772242}, {66.28477905, 
   64.25233645}, {1.490066225, 1.914414414}, {1.474926254, 
   1.763224181}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {-5, 100}},
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[
    StringTrim[{"DT401       ", "DT402       ", "DT403       ", 
      "DT404       ", "DT405       ", "DT406       ", "DT407       ", 
      "DT408       ", "DT409       ", "DT410       ", "DT411       ", 
      "DT412       "}
     ], Axis], Placed[{"", ""}, Bottom]}]
```

[image: barchart]